# Get into fastboot mode (AOC Q70S15 model)

Tags: fastboot, linux

Model: AOC Q70S15
Android version: 4.2.2
Tablet not rooted
Desktop OS: Arch Linux

Issuing the command `adb reboot fastboot` from my pc makes the tablet shut down but it doesn't reboot, the same happens with `adb reboot`, nothing change if I do it with sudo.

According to the [manual](https://fccid.io/QAPQ70S15/User-Manual/User-manual-2064334): Press and hold the power button and volume button 3 seconds at the same time. Release the buttons and tablet will boot and an Android robot will be displayed. However 3 seconds doesn't do anything, two scenarios occur when I maintain pressed the buttons for longer time:

1. After some seconds (10-15) the tablet starts booting but not in fastboot but the normal way, however if I release the tablet buttons it goes off inmediatelly.
2. Sometimes nothing happens.

Comment: *adb reboot bootloader* or *adb reboot-bootloader* or *Volume Down + Power*

Answer (score 1):

Keeping pressed `Volume Down + Power` for 6 secs did the trick, after that you need to wait like 5 secs and the android robot should appear, then you press the `Power` button and without releasing it press the `Volume Up` button one time, now you are the system recovery.

Comment: why is question about fastboot mode but answer for recovery mode?

Comment: Sorry got a little confuse, when I was searching about fastboot mode before post here, the results I found were about entering the recovery mode so I thought they were the same. If this is not correct what is exactly the fastboot mode, the screen with just the android robot?

Comment: that's a different [mode](https://droidrecovery.com/wp-content/uploads/Android-Boot-Mode-768x323.jpg) for flashing

Comment: I see thank you for the clarification, now I think I'm going to delete this this question and maybe open a more specific one but before that, just to make sure, when I do de volumen down + power I end in this android robot screen, from there what I need to do to enter in fastboot mode?

Comment: do not delete that question. it seems that tablet don't have fastboot mode

Comment: It could be, but if this was the case are there ways to install a fastboot? or this is the end of the road? The reason I need to enter in fastboot is because I want to root this tablet so I can install linux on it.